# How to SUM by date range within a view

Tags: t-sql, view, group-by, computed-column

I have a view in which I need to Group By or SUM OVER Partition By year and quarter, but the year and quarter will be computed within the view. I would like to keep it all within a view instead of needing tables and SPs.

The goal is to get SUMs by of all records within the first quarter of a year, spanning over multiple years. What I have is:

```
SELECT MIN(PAYROLL)                     AS MinPayroll
      ,MAX(PAYROLL)                     AS MaxPayroll
      ,YEAR(CHECK_DATE)                 AS PayrollYear
      ,MONTH(CHECK_DATE)                AS PayrollMonth
      ,SUM(sit)                         AS TotalStateTax
      ,SUM(FIT)                         AS TotalFedTax
...
...
FROM CHECKS 
WHERE (PayrollMonth = 01 OR PayrollMonth = 02 OR PayrollMonth = 03)
GROUP BY PayrollYear
```

This gives a good idea of what I want to do, but SSMS doesn't like it, saying `'Invalid column name 'PayrollMonth'`, and `'Invalid Column name 'PayrollYear'`

I'll start working on sample data to help, but I wanted to get this out now in case someone knew what to do off the top of their heads without data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use columns aliased in the `SELECT` list directly in the `WHERE` clause. See [blog post here](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2015/07/logical-query-processing/). Full disclosure; I wrote it.

You'd have to do this. Note that leading zeroes are discarded for integers.

```
SELECT MIN(PAYROLL)                     AS MinPayroll
      ,MAX(PAYROLL)                     AS MaxPayroll
      ,YEAR(CHECK_DATE)                 AS PayrollYear
      ,MONTH(CHECK_DATE)                AS PayrollMonth
      ,SUM(sit)                         AS TotalStateTax
      ,SUM(FIT)                         AS TotalFedTax
...
...
FROM CHECKS 
WHERE MONTH(CHECK_DATE) = 1 OR MONTH(CHECK_DATE) = 2 OR MONTH(CHECK_DATE) = 3
GROUP BY YEAR(CHECK_DATE);
```

Or use a `CTE`

```
WITH really_bad_idea AS (
SELECT MIN(PAYROLL)                     AS MinPayroll
      ,MAX(PAYROLL)                     AS MaxPayroll
      ,YEAR(CHECK_DATE)                 AS PayrollYear
      ,MONTH(CHECK_DATE)                AS PayrollMonth
      ,SUM(sit)                         AS TotalStateTax
      ,SUM(FIT)                         AS TotalFedTax
...
...
FROM CHECKS 
GROUP BY YEAR(CHECK_DATE)
)
SELECT *
FROM really_bad_dea
WHERE (PayrollMonth = 1 OR PayrollMonth = 2 OR PayrollMonth = 3);
```

Though I would ask very nicely that you not write non-SARGable `WHERE` clauses like that, because they are performance nightmares.

Also, it's doubltful the query will compile with just that column in the `GROUP BY`.

Comment: Do you mean that the `really_bad_idea CTE` is the non-SARGable, or your first example?

Comment: @sp_BlitzErik, regarding the non-SARGable part of your answer; what would suggestion be? Using `BETWEEN` instead of  the 2 `OR`'s?

Comment: @Jeff.Clark both are non-SARGable. Neither is a good idea, performance-wise.

Comment: @Jason no, `BETWEEN`/`OR` won't make a lick of difference.

Comment: Really then, the business requirement to have it all done within one view is creating the performance hit?

Comment: @Jeff.Clark as written, yes.

Comment: Indeed, it did not compile as written above. SSMS did not like `CHECK_DATE` not being in an aggregate or group by. I just ended up doing a `MAX(MONTH((CHECK_DATE))` and `MIN(MONTH(CHECK_DATE))` since at this point they are just for dev purposes to make sure I am getting the correct data.